# How to make mobileconfig file on ios device

Tags: ios

Detail: Every stuff in our company has his own calendar and a fixed subscribe url, which is known, I am working on an iOS app, which can help stuffs to install a mobileconfig file and automatically subscribe the calendar, I just don't know where to start

Here is an example of 163EMAIL: https://ssl.mail.163.com/config/mobileconfig/index
I am trying to make one exactly like this!

if all this can be done within only one iOS device will be better.

so all you have is an url of a calendar, with which I can manually subscribe by entering setting-email-add-other-subscribe
and I want to make it a mobileconfig file!

THX!

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/iPhoneOTAConfiguration/Introduction/Introduction.html) is a good place to start.

"Creating a Profile Server for Over-The-Air Enrollment and Configuration" is the part you should really focus on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in Apple Configurator on OS X